# profile(.MobileConfig) install from safari, then return back to app

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, safari, mobile-safari, payload

I am working on a project that has the user install a profile (.MobileConfig) on an iOS device. The current flow is as followed(each step is initiated by the user; sub-steps are antonymous):

1) Button click in app that directs to safari
    - switches to settings app for profile install
2) User may either install or cancel
    - switches back to safari
3) User manually directs back to app

However this is one too many steps. The flow I would like is as followed (each step is initiated by the user; sub-steps are antonymous):

1) Button click in app that directs to safari
    - switches to settings app for profile install
2) User may either install or cancel
    - switches back to safari
    - switches back to app

I am aware I can place a button for the user to click that will direct back to my app but I would like to make this process as antonymous as possible. This flow is found in the app Onavo, but I have yet to find any information regarding how to do this.

Comment: @usman arham
using a routing http server u can get back to ur app from the settings app after ur profile is installed or even if the installation is cancelled.. this worked for me.. gd luck (Y) 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338035/installing-a-configuration-profile-on-iphone-programmatically

Comment: Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959244/is-it-possible-in-javascript-to-detect-when-the-screen-is-turned-off-in-the-an
Works for me pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

The Example Onavo that you have quoted is a native application.

The Process you want is not yet possible in web apps, this is limitations of a web app in ios
You can not even not download mobile config in a full screen web app. But in a web with not normal viewport (not full screen web app) mobile config will be downloaded and then will be redirected to safari after user cancels or installs the app

Comment: You're missing the point, in Onavo, the app 1) opens Safari and 2) prompts the user to install a profile and then after the profile is/is not intalled, 3) redirects the user to the app from safari